# Removing slave nodes while execution in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to somehow tell the master node not to assign any more tasks to a certain worker node in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed blog on node blacklisting.

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/04/blacklisting-in-apache-spark/